# Can someone explain through integration, why the area under the $v(t)$ graph represents $x$ (displacement)?

Tags: integration

My problem with this concept is that whenever I obtain the expression for Area under the graph
i.e.

$\displaystyle \text{Area of the entire function under v is} \int v(t) dt$
Area of a single, infinitesimal strip is $v(t)dt$

Now, why is this equal to $x$?

Comment: What's the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$? As an aside, an indefinite integral is doesn't represent an area; it represents an antiderivative. Definite integrals represent areas.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.  Please clarify x.  Do you mean the position?

Comment: I have posted an explanation. Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

How far does the object travel if it is going $v$ for a duration $\Delta t$?  Of course, distance = speed times time, so $d = v \Delta t$.  The graph shows the velocity versus time, and the red rectangle indicates the distance the object moves from $t = .6$ to $t = .6 + \Delta t$.  The rectangle has height $v$ and width $\Delta t$, so its area is $v \Delta t$, which is the distance traveled.

[image: Distance traveled in Delta t]

That happens at every moment, so you add up all those rectangles to get the total distance traveled.

[image: Add up distances]

In the limit of small $\Delta t$, that red area is just the area under the graph.  In the limit $\Delta t \to 0$:

[image: integral is limit of small Delta t]

or

$$d = \int v(t)\ dt$$

Got it?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $v(t)$ refers to the instantaneous velocity at time $t$. Then, if $ds$ is the displacement of the object in time interval $dt$, we have
$$ds = v(t)\, dt$$
Intuitively, we assume that the time interval $dt$ is small enough, so that $v(t)$ is more or less constant in $[t, t + dt]$. In other words, $v(t) \approx v(t+dt)$. Now, we sum up all these *small* displacements $ds$ to get the total displacement $x$, as desired. If we need the displacement from time $t_1$ to $t_2$, we do
$$x = \int_0^x ds = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} v(t)\, dt$$
As you may already know, $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} v(t)\, dt$ also represents the area under the curve of $v(t)$ versus $t$ - this is what the Riemann integral really is.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of what is known as the **Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**. Simply put, the theorem describes integrals as the inverse of derivatives.

Here's an example.

> Supposed you drive $100$ miles in $2$ hours.

**What would be your average speed?**

Your *average* rate of change would be $50 \cfrac{\text{miles}}{\text{hour}}$, or $50$ miles per hour. However, this doesn't mean that's the speed you went the entire time; it's merely the *average*.

**What would be your speed at, say, the ninth minute of the drive?**

This is when the *derivative* comes in. It lets you know how fast you are moving *at a nearly instantaneous* point. (The reason why I say "nearly instantaneous" is because "instantaneous rate of change" is self-contradictory by nature and also because it involves limits).

**Now what if you only knew the speed but you knew how much time you spent?**
This is where the definite integral comes in. But, just step back and think about it. If someone told you that they drove at a constant $50$ miles per hour for $2$ hours, you would instantly know that their total *displacement*, or distance traveled, was $100$ miles. But what you did intuitively here can actually be expressed as a definite integral:
$$\displaystyle \int_0^2 50tdt$$

Now you make ask, what's the $dt$ for? Not only does $dt$ tell us that we're integrating in terms of $t$, or time, but it's also the *width* of the infinitesimally small rectangles that we add up for the *area*.

To visualize this, let's go back to the example integral above. The graph of this is a simple triangle, but we want to approximate, and eventually, find the exact value, of the area using rectangles. If $t=0$, then the height, or the function value at $t=0$, is also $50 \cdot 0 = 0$. Set another point at $t=1$. This time, the function value is $50 \cdot 1$, or $50$. Now, to get a rectangle, we need the two t-values, $1$ and $0$, and their respective function values, $50$ and $0$. Choosing the **right Riemann sum**, we can set the width to $1 - 0 = 1$ and the height to $50 - 0 = 50$. Continuing this process, we can *approximate* the value of the integral.

However, to be more precise, we need to make the width smaller. This, we assign as $dt$, or the *small difference in $t$*. By taking the limit as $dt$ gets closer to 0, we can get more and more exact representations of the area, until we get the precise *definite integral*, which represents the exact area under the function.

This area represents the total distance, and remember that this area can be found by breaking it up into an infinitely high number of small rectangles. These rectangles have a height based on the *function value* at that point, and their width is the small increments by which you break up the total area - that width is $dt$.

Hopefully, this also helped you conceptually understand the relationship between *average rate of change*, the *derivative*, and the *definite integral* in the context of motion.